# VBScript: Appending a word to the MS "Word" 2003 document

Tags: vbscript, windows-xp, ms-word

Here is a short code that opens my "fox.doc" :

```
Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wd.Visible = True
Set doc = wd.Documents.Open("c:\fox.doc")
```

I need to add only one word "bottle" in the end of this document (after it has been opened). Which lines should I add to my small vbs script for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can learn a lot by recording macros in Word and then making the, usually small, changes that will make the code work in VBScript.

```
Set r = doc.Words.Last
r.InsertAfter (" bottle")
```

Comment: Thank you Remou. I have added these two lines to the script and now it works! How did you come up with these two lines? "*You can learn a lot by recording macros in Word and then making the small changes that will make the code work in VBScript*" - but that's exactly what I did before posting this question. I did record a small macro, and I got only one line then: `Selection.TypeText Text:="bottle"` However, when I added this line to the code, it didn't work. What did I do wrong then?

Comment: You need to start recording from when you open the document, so you may have typed ctlr+End, which would have given you `Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory`, however, recording macros is not the whole story, I admit, you can also use intellisense to explore what is available. Intellisense really comes into its own when you declare objects `As` something suitable, for example, `Dim doc As Document`, now when you type `doc.`, you will get a list of options to explore. (cont)

Comment: (cont) You cannot do this in VBScript, so it is useful to work in VBA at first. Other very useful tools include the Object Browser, Watch and (tada) F1.

Comment: I see, thank you. "*You cannot do this in VBScript, so it is useful to work in VBA at first*" - Yes, but as far as I can see, VBA is good for writing and working with macros while you are using "Word", while my current need is to automatize the process of modifying (or adding things to) my "Word" documents without opening them - so that's why I need to learn how to program in the outside-of-word-working VBS.